# Does the Samsung NP-RV711 laptop support Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, tpm

Holiday season is approaching - understand the maintenance season for my relatives’ computers

I’ve been asked for support to reformat an old laptop from 2012. AFAIK it is still running Windows 7 to date. I currently don’t have access to the laptop and I cannot ask the user to perform “complicated” diagnostic steps. They were kind enough to give me the reference though.

Wondering which Windows version is supported there - to prepare the corresponding ISO image for my upcoming visit.

## Tech Specs

Samsung NP-RV711

- 17,3” 1600 x 900
- Intel® CoreTM i3, i3-380m 2,53 GHz (2 Cores, 4 Threads), 64bit
- 4 GB DDR3-SDRAM (2x SO-DIMM, max. 8 GB)
- HDD 640 GB SATA
- Intel HD Graphics: Intel GMA 4500MHD

## Windows 11 requirements

The laptop ticks most Windows 11 [requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-11-system-requirements-86c11283-ea52-4782-9efd-7674389a7ba3):

- Processors/CPUs (Central Processing Units): 1 Ghz or faster with 2 or more cores and appearing on our list of approved CPUs.
- RAM: 4 GB.
- Storage: 64 GB or larger storage device.
- System Firmware: UEFI (for Unified Extensible Firmware Interface, a modern version of the PC BIOS) and Secure Boot capable.
- TPM: Trusted Platform Module (TPM) version 2.0.
- Graphics Card: Compatible with DirectX 12 or later with WDDM 2.0 driver.
- Display: High definition (720p) display that is greater than 9” diagonally, 8 bits per color channel.
- Internet Connectivity and Microsoft Accounts.

So the question boils down to whether this laptop supports TPM 2.0. Is that the case?

Comment: Microsoft has utilities that will check for 11 compatibility.

Comment: Your requirements link has a list of supported processors in the  section. You might be able to force the installation but update may or may not happen.

Comment: The answer is no, if you didn't get the hints already.

Comment: Note: I don't have access to the laptop at the moment, and the user is not proficient enough to ask them to install a tool to check compatibility.

Comment: The user only needs to be able to open settings > updates. In the top right corner it'll tell them it doesn't support Windows 11, if it's running Windows 10 already, of course. In a nutshell, although there are 'hacks' to work around the requirements problems will occur sooner than later even in machines that are almost there but not quite - a couple of generations older CPU. older TPM, etc. - , **doing it in a 10+ years old ENTRY LEVEL laptop is the textbook definition of insanity.** This is what you *should* do: (...)

Comment: (...) Max out RAM - 8GB RAM -, replace the old rusty HDD with a SATA SSD (128GB is more than enough for OS and lots of software; keep personal files and especially large media files somewhere else), **install any mainstream user-friendly Linux (Ubuntu flavors like Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu-Budgie, Linux Mint, etc.)**

Comment: There is nothing stopping you downloading the iso from Microsoft & doing a test install.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Understood that Win11 is not an option. I consider preparing ISOs for both Win10 and Ubuntu and let the user decide.

Answer (score -1):

Found a video on YouTube:

[Can We Save A 10 Year Old laptop From The Dump? Samsung RV711 Repair and Turn On.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm2SfCLV1e0&t=0s)

Apparently installing Windows 10 is possible.

Couldn’t find any wording looking like “TPM” in the BIOS screens though. So I’d assume Windows 11 is not supported.

[image: BIOS Advanced screen Samsung RV711]